# Vuforia-Samples in Android Studio Error

Tags: android, gradle, vuforia

I load the Vuforia project into Android Studio and get this Error-Message:

Migrate Project to Gradle?
This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.

+

Error running build: Cannot find script C:\Users...\vuforia\v2\samples\app\build.gradle

Actually the build.gradle file is in this folder.

I followed these Steps:

```
Close your project
Back up your project
Delete the .idea folder in the root directory of the project
Delete all the .iml files in your project
Import your project in Android Studio, and in the dialog that prompts you for a file, choose the build.gradle file.
```

,but not successfully.

Sorry for my bad english.